# Do I always need to call wp_get_current_user() before accessing $current_user?

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple plugin that runs when a user logs in and logs out. (I'm a PHP n00b and this is purely educational)

It references **$current_user** (defined as global in the function). And it all works as it should.

Except, of all the code snippets I've seen that reference **$current_user**, some call **wp_get_current_user()** beforehand, and some don't.

My question is... should wp_get_current_user() always be called before accessing $current_user - or is it safe to presume wp_get_current_user() has already been called (with the caveat the code is running in the WordPress Admin panel - so a user MUST logged in)?

Reason I ask is... it seems inefficient to call a function that's already been called (and if a user's logged in then it *must* have been called, right?), but also we should never presume anything (what if, for some bizarre reason, the name $current_user is changed in Core in the future).

Of course, there's a third option that's only just sprung to mind... test whether $current_user is already set/defined and if it isn't, call wp_get_current_user().

TBH this last option seems like the best 'efficiency vs robustness' compromise - but I'm still curious to hear which people think is the best way and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a best practice, you should call `wp_current_user()` because you can't assume that `$current_user` is set (or if it is set correctly with the user you're after).

> Of course, there's a third option that's only just sprung to mind...
>   test whether $current_user is already set/defined and if it isn't,
>   call wp_get_current_user().

Actually, that's kind of what happens already.  [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) is just a wrapper for the private method [`_wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_current_user/), so you can look at that function to see what it does.  The first thing it does is check if `$current_user` exists and is populated, and if so, it returns `$current_user`.

To address your question of efficiency/inefficiency, since the method is already checking to see if `$current_user` is loaded, it would actually be more inefficient if you were doing it, then running `wp_get_current_user()` since that would be an unnecessary step.